# Initial guesses for hyperparameters in GPflow

Tags: hyperparameters, gpflow

I've also asked this on the [GPflow GitHub](https://github.com/GPflow/GPflow/issues/1517#issue-646722550)

I found the initial guesses for hyperparameters by using `m.likelihood.variance.assign(0.01)` and `m.kernel.lengthscales.assign(0.3)` affects significantly to the final optimized hyperparameters. I was wondering if there is a method to get a good initial guess? For example, estimating using the dataset.

Answer (score 0):

As [pointed out by Mark](https://github.com/GPflow/GPflow/issues/1517#issuecomment-650599502) on the GPflow GitHub, this is a common issue for GPs in general, irrespective of the implementation (whether in GPflow or other packages), and this [draft article on Distill](https://drafts.distill.pub/gp/) discusses it in a lot of depth.

Answer (score 0):

You could try using a global optimizer like `scipy.optimize.basinhopping()` instead of the typical `scipy.optimize.minimize()` or `tf.optimizers.adam()` local optimizers.  That would at least give you more confidence that you are not getting stuck in the nearest local optimum.